# Separate locators from page object classes Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to implement POM model in my autotests and I have a problem with separating locators to another file. I am using this as guide 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

My page object

```
from Locators.Sites.SitesLocators import SitesLocators

class ResetPasswordFirstForm(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)

    def button_go_to_reset_passwrod(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*SitesLocators.button_go_to_reset_password).click()

    def button_submit_form(self):
        self.driver.find_element(*SitesLocators.button_submit_reset_password).click()
```

My locators

```
class SitesLocators(object):

    button_go_to_reset_password = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#/reset-password']")
    button_submit_reset_password = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[ng-click='send()']")
```

But i get this error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

What is the best way to separate my locators and use them correct?

Comment: on what line do you get the error?

Comment: On first locator usage 
self.driver.find_element(*SitesLocators.button_go_to_reset_password).click()

Comment: have you tried to change the element name or the function name you shouldn't use the same name... `button_go_to_reset_passwrod`

Comment: Yes, i have already noticed it, didin`t help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it the Error:

> TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Means you need to add a third argument to the `__init()__`:

This is your current `__init()__`:

```
def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver
    self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
```

As you quoted in your question the [selenium page-objects](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) you can see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#page-elements) that they have a third argument (although not always used see `owner`).

So just add a third one it should do the trick!

As you can see here:

```
def __get__(self, obj, owner):
    """Gets the text of the specified object"""
    driver = obj.driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
        lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator))
    element = driver.find_element_by_name(self.locator)
    return element.get_attribute("value")
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: but how do i need to initialize 'owner', and where is it used?. In examples where is basepage class only with 2 varriables in init, self and driver, and where is any 3third agrument http://joxi.ru/52a73Vlh4KvW5r Can you write how my init must look like, i don`t get it, ty

Comment: @NiPa as you can see in the pic you sent... there is a `BasePageElement` inherited in the `SearchTextElement` obj. we initialize it in `MainPage`